# Execute custom action after file upload completed in fine-uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

Is it possible to execute a custom action on upload-completed? I would like to move the uploaded file to another location on the server once it has been uploaded. Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you're trying to execute operations on the server-side, then FineUploader will not be able to help you. If you're trying to make something happen client-side, then check out the [documentation on callbacks](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html).

Comment: Thank you, callbacks were what I was looking for. I achieved my goal through an ajax call to a .php page on the server which moves the uploaded file to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark stated, what happens server-side is entirely up to you.  Simply move the file to whatever location you want, whenever you want.  Fine Uploader is a client-side library.  You must either write your own server-side code to handle Fine Uploader's requests, or use one of the many [server-side examples](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server).